# In Pycharm CSS attributes are not populating automatically

Tags: html, css, pycharm

Using pycharm and creating a frontend but I am having a problem with the css in pycharm, It does not automatically populate the attributes. I have to write complete code for it. i.e writing a border should automatically populate the list of relevant attributes which is not appearing. [image]

please help me as how this can be fixed? or if you have any other editor suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly but by default web development files like JS/HTML/CSS are only supported in Professional Edition. Look [PyCharm Editions Comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: I have created html files as well through pycharm but it works good but having issues with the css only. how about atom IDE?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not using Pycharm Professional Edition . You can use sublime text or others editor and run the program in command line .